# Confusing in periodic semigroup

Tags: semigroups

[image]

Can anyone tell my, why we have to mod $r$ ? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a^{m+r}=a^m$ then all operations with  exponents are performed on $\mod r$.

Comment: Do I am right? Now, we consider elements in $K_{a}$ and know that if $a^{n}=a^{m}$, then $n=m$. Thus we have $m+u+m+x=m+v$. I struck here and I cannot connect it to $\mod r$.

Comment: No. You can only say that if $a^s = a^t$ is an element of $K_a$, then $s \equiv t \bmod r$. For instance, you have $a^m = a^{m+r}$, but $m \not= m +r$.

Comment: Thanks. And I have a question. Are the elements in $K_{a}$ all distinct?

Comment: @J.-E. Pin: thank you for help :-)

Comment: @nameless: Yes, they are distinct.

Comment: If all elements in $K_{a}$  are all distinct, then for two elements in $K_{a}$, $a^{m+u}, a^{m+v}$ such that $a^{m+u}=a^{m+v}$. Why we don not have $m+u=m+v$?

Comment: @nameless: All distinct elements of $K_a$ are: $a^m,\ldots,a^{m+r-1}$. So, for example, $a^{m+r}=a^m\in K_a$, but $m+r\ne m$!

Comment: I got it!!! Thank you.

Comment: @nameless: You are welcome!